# Abnormal termination error running supervisor

Tags: supervisord

I'm trying to use supervisor with nginx, but I haven't been able to get to the nginx part yet because I'm screwing something up with supervisor.

I can run

```
sudo supervisorctl reread
```

and it will say "site_demo: available". Then I run

```
sudo supervisorctl update
```

and it says "site_demo: updated process group". So that seems fine. But then I try to run

```
sudo supervisorctl start site_demo
```

and I get the error

```
site_demo: ERROR (abnormal termination)
```

Here is my supervisor.conf file:

```
; supervisor config file

[unix_http_server]
file=/var/run//supervisor.sock   ; (the path to the socket file)
chmod=0700                       ; sockef file mode (default 0700)

[supervisord]
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
childlogdir=/var/log/supervisor            ; ('AUTO' child log dir, default $TEMP)

; the below section must remain in the config file for RPC
; (supervisorctl/web interface) to work, additional interfaces may be
; added by defining them in separate rpcinterface: sections
[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///var/run//supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket

; The [include] section can just contain the "files" setting.  This
; setting can list multiple files (separated by whitespace or
; newlines).  It can also contain wildcards.  The filenames are
; interpreted as relative to this file.  Included files *cannot*
; include files themselves.

[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf
```

And here is demo.conf, the one file included under [include]:

```
[program:site_demo]

directory=/home/snorthway/demo/website

environment=PYTHONPATH=/home/snorthway/python-envs/demo

command=/home/snorthway/python-envs/demo/bin/python /home/snorthway/demo/website/manage.py runfcgi method=prefork  socket=/home/snorthway/eft/demo/fcgi/socket pidfile=/home/snorthway/eft/demo/fcgi/demo.pid minspare=4 maxspare=10 daemonize=false

redirect_stderr=true

stdout_logfile=/home/snorthway/eft/demo/logs/demo.fcgi.log

autostart=true

user=www-data
```

I checked that all of the paths in there exist and whatnot, so I don't think that's the problem.

My log file looks like this:

```
2013-06-24 15:40:23,548 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2013-06-24 15:40:23,566 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2013-06-24 15:40:23,566 WARN cElementTree not installed, using slower XML parser for XML-RPC
2013-06-24 15:40:23,566 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2013-06-24 15:40:23,566 INFO daemonizing the supervisord process
2013-06-24 15:40:23,566 INFO supervisord started with pid 8896
2013-06-24 16:08:27,262 INFO spawned: 'site_demo' with pid 9221
2013-06-24 16:08:27,464 INFO exited: site_demo (exit status 0; not expected)
2013-06-24 16:08:28,469 INFO spawned: 'site_demo' with pid 9226
2013-06-24 16:08:28,667 INFO exited: site_demo (exit status 0; not expected)
2013-06-24 16:08:30,672 INFO spawned: 'site_demo' with pid 9231
2013-06-24 16:08:30,863 INFO exited: site_demo (exit status 0; not expected)
2013-06-24 16:08:33,870 INFO spawned: 'site_demo' with pid 9240
2013-06-24 16:08:34,077 INFO exited: site_demo (exit status 0; not expected)
2013-06-24 16:08:35,079 INFO gave up: site_demo entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if I had looked at demo.fcgi.log I would have figured this out a long time ago. It consisted entirely of this error:

```
ERROR: No module named flup
  Unable to load the flup package.  In order to run django
  as a FastCGI application, you will need to get flup from
  http://www.saddi.com/software/flup/   If you've already
  installed flup, then make sure you have it in your PYTHONPATH.
```

So I did

```
pip install flup
sudo supervisorctl reread # This may not have been necessary
sudo supervisorctl update
sudo supervisorctl start site_demo
```

and it worked!

Comment: Hi, where was this demo.fcgi.log located? I am trying to examine something similar, but can't locate that log

Comment: Hi @dabad, it's whatever you set `stdout_logfile` to in your supervisor config file(s). I set mine in `demo.conf` if you look in the question. If you didn't set `stdout_logfile`, the default appears to be `$CWD/supervisord.log` (see http://supervisord.org/logging.html). Good luck!